# In PySpark 1.5.0, how do you list all items of column `y` based on the values of column `x`?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

The following question is specific to version 1.5.0 of PySpark, as new features are being constantly added to PySpark.

How do you list all items of column `y` based on the values of column `x`? 
For example:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([ {'x': "foo", 'y': 1}, 
                  {'x': "foo", 'y': 1}, 
                  {'x': "bar", 'y': 10}, 
                 {'x': "bar", 'y': 2},
                 {'x': 'qux', 'y':999}])
df = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(rdd)
df.show()

+---+---+
|  x|  y|
+---+---+
|foo|  1|
|foo|  1|
|bar| 10|
|bar|  2|
|qux|999|
+---+---+
```

I would like to have something like:

```
+---+--------+
|  x|  y     |
+---+--------+
|foo| [1, 1] |
|bar| [10, 2]|
|bar| [999]  |
+---+--------+
```

The order doesn't matter. In Pandas, I can achieve this usign groupby:

```
pd = df.toPandas()
pd.groupby('x')['y'].apply(list).reset_index()
```

However, `groupBy` aggregation functionality in ver 1.5.0 seems to be very limited. Any idea how to overcome this limitation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `collect_list` Hive UDAF:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr
from pyspark import HiveContext

sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd)

df.groupBy("x").agg(expr("collect_list(y) AS y"))
```

In 1.6 or later you can use collect_list function:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import collect_list

df.groupBy("x").agg(collect_list(y).alias("y"))
```

and in 2.0 or later you can use it without Hive support.

This is not a particularly efficient operation though so you should use it with moderation.

Also, don't use dictionaries for schema inference. It's been deprecated since 1.2

Comment: +1 for a really helpful answer (for my purposes), but the OP asked for 1.5 and `collect_list` is new in 1.6 http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=dataframe#pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list

Comment: Has anyone looked at how `group_by` + `collect_list` compares to `rdd.groupBy` in terms of efficiency, robustness, etc?

Comment: @Paul `collect_list` is a Hive UDAF not a native Spark operation. 1.6.0 just introduced a `DataFrame` API wrapper. That's why it has to be used here via `expr` (or a SQL query).

Comment: shouldn't it be `groupBy`? Plus: `AnalysisException: undefined function collect_list;` Do I ned to import anything else?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I am just typing from memory. It is a Hive UDAF so you have to use it with Hive Context not a plain `SQLContext`.